# Why does modifying what list() return not work?

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a list that contains three strings, and I want a new list that drops one of the strings. I know there are alternate ways of doing this, but I was surprised that the following does not work:

```
x = ['A','B','C']

y = list(x).remove('A')
```

Why does the above not work?

Edit: Thanks for the answers everyone!

Comment: I suppose it depends on what you think it "working" means.

Comment: `x.remove('A')` should work. `list(x).remove('A')` creates a new list and remove `A` from the newly created list. So even if you print `x` after removing the element `A` will still be there.

Comment: `list.remove()` returns `None`. It's documented as doing so, and this is on purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Per [the Python Programming FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html?highlight=mutate%20return%20none#why-did-changing-list-y-also-change-list-x) (emphasis added):

> Some operations (for example `y.append(10)` and `y.sort()`) mutate the object, whereas superficially similar operations (for example `y = y + [10]` and `sorted(y)`) create a new object. **In general in Python (and in all cases in the standard library) a method that mutates an object will return `None` to help avoid getting the two types of operations confused.** So if you mistakenly write `y.sort()` thinking it will give you a sorted copy of `y`, you’ll instead end up with `None`, which will likely cause your program to generate an easily diagnosed error.

Since `remove` is a mutating method (changes the `list` it's called on in-place), it follows the general pattern of returning `None`. If it didn't, a line like:

```
y = x.remove('A')
```

would appear to work, but it would be aliasing `y` to the same `list` referenced by `x`, not creating a new `list` at all, and it might take some time for that mistake to be noticed, even as you use `x` and `y` believing them to be independent. By returning `None`, any attempt to use `y` believing it to be a separate `list` (or a `list` at all), will likely fail loudly (as it does in your case, with or without the `list` wrapping, making your misuse of `remove` obvious).

This also generally encourages Python's (loose) guideline to avoid shoving too many steps in a process on a single line. If you want to copy a `list` and remove one element, you do it in two steps:

```
y = list(x)
y.remove('A')
```

and it works just fine.